# HDD in external case SATA/USB3.0: stop automatic disk switch off

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, enclosures, sata-to-usb

I recently bought a sharkoon swift case pro USB3.0, external 3.5" HDD case/enclosure. The problem(s) is:

When I reboot windows (doesnt matter which version it seems, tried both xp/7), the case shuts down the hdd and starts it again (this is the worst thing for a mechanical disk).

Strange thing is that when you forcefully remove the USB cable while the case is ON, the HDD wont shut down; this is to expected because its the case that gives the power to the HDD.
Also the HDD shuts down after a while, when inactive until I access the disk (power saving).

It seems that (not 100% sure though) this won't happen if the enclosure and the HDD are ATA (old connection cables).

So, how to keep the hdd ON as long as the case is ON? Is it just this case or it also happens with other SATA/USB cases as well?

Edit: It would be informative if you could share your personal experience (if any of course) with SATA/USB cases.

Comment: Many external enclosure do all sorts of fancy things. Some smart, some not so smart. Usually that means 'all bets are off' when you use a enclosure with a USB->SATA bridge.

Comment: Do you have any actual *evidence* that power-cycling the HDD will do it any harm? The bearings will not be cooling down significantly in those few seconds.

Comment: generally, its a bad thing, switching on and off the hdd, shortens the lifespan/wears more the hdd.  -personal 10year+ experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firmware of this enclosure does this. Nothing to do about it (unless someone has the level to hack it)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to attack the problem:

1. In Windows: Prevent the USB-to-SATA-Adapter from giving the instruction to power down the drive based on the assumptions Windows does make - which can be a problem if the adapter in use does not provide enough sensor-data to Windows (either due to the adapter or a generic driver). You achieve this by enabling the disk-cache in the properties of the drive. When you do that you are forced to unmount the drive manually.

Alternatively, if you are able to prepare a linux-live-system on a USB-drive - for example Ubuntu or Fedora:

2. You may access the drives settings e.g. via the "Disks"-tool provided by the Gnome-Desktop. If the adapter allows it you may be able to access the spinup-rate and automatic-powerdown setting of the drive and set it to not powerdown. This "might" hinder Windows from giving the order to powerdown the drive - assuming the adapter does translate/report the drive-configuration correctly.

While there are other ways to try to achieve this, they require a deep understanding of the hardware, the interfaces and require absolute precision when applying the commands, which is only possible in a terminal and by attaching the actual drive directly (without the adapter in between) to an internal SATA-controller - and even then are not guaranteed to provide a solution.